# Regexp capture part of text but ignores rest if patern found

Tags: regex, pcre, zabbix, capture-group

Using regexp I need to "filter" some text but only if part of line matches pattern.

Sample input is (each line is separate record):

```
OK: ALL OK (8536972.66889)
ERROR: ioerror/8536615.22927
OK: ALL OK (8546369.92291)
```

In case `"OK: ALL OK"` I need filter out (float) in other cases all line should match. Every match should be in "the same capture group" (the same means always e.x. in 4 capture group). So correct output should be

```
OK: ALL OK
OK: ALL OK
ERROR: ioerror/8536615.22927
OK: ALL OK
```

I've tried:
`((OK: ALL OK) (?:\(.*\))|ERROR: .*)`

and got result:

```
Match 1:
Group 1: OK: ALL OK (8536972.66889)
Group 2: OK: ALL OK

Match 2:
Group1: ERROR: ioerror/8536615.22927
```

I need `"OK: ALL OK"` or `"ERROR: ioerror/8536615.22927"` always in the same capture group, any ideas how to do these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the matches all in group 1, you can use a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) as the outer group, and put the ERROR part in it's own group:

```
(?|(OK: ALL OK) (?:\(.*\))|(ERROR: .*))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Y89q7/1)

Al alternative without capture groups and using a lookahead assertion to assert a `(...)` part after matching `OK: ALL OK`

```
\bERROR:\h.*|\bOK:\hALL\hOK(?=\h+\([^()]*\))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lefwto/1)